# Javascript - Import not found

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, node-modules

I'm trying to make a text-mask GitHub repository work with my laravel project, With this, I want to use a certain addon which allows me to mask an input field as a price. The GitHub repository I'm talking about is [linked here](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/)

The addon is called `createNumberMask` and on their github page it says the following in their documentation:

```
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask'

// First, you need to create the `numberMask` with your desired configurations
const numberMask = createNumberMask({
   prefix: '',
   suffix: ' $' // This will put the dollar sign at the end, with a space.
})

// ...then pass `numberMask` to the Text Mask component as the mask
```

Now when I try to implement this into my own project it gives me the error saying that the import cannot be found. What is causing this?

I have a blade file which has script tags at the bottom of it. The blade file looks like this,

```
@section('content')
<div class="row " style="color: white; width: 100%; margin: 0;" id="showEffect">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="margin-top: 10rem">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" class="myInput form-control depth-5">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<script type="module">

    import createNumberMask from '/node_modules/text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask'

    const numberMask = createNumberMask({
        prefix: '€',
        suffix: '',
        allowDecimal: true,
    });

    var myInput = document.querySelector('myInput');

    var maskedInputController = vanillaTextMask.maskInput({
        inputElement: document.querySelector('myInput'),
        mask: numberMask
    });


</script>

@endsection
```

Why is the import not working? The js file is inside the node_modules folder.

APP.JS

```
require('./bootstrap');

import TextMask from 'vanilla-text-mask/dist/vanillaTextMask';
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';

window.Vue = require('vue');

window.events = new Vue();

window.flash = function (message) {
    window.events.$emit('flash', message);
};


Vue.component('flash', require('./components/Flash.vue'));

// Vue.component('product-view', require('./components/Products.vue'));
// Vue.component('wysiwyg', require('./components/Wysiwyg.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
});

const numberMask = createNumberMask({
prefix: '€',
suffix: '',
allowDecimal: true,
});

var myInput = document.querySelector('myInput');

var maskedInputController = vanillaTextMask.maskInput({
    inputElement: document.querySelector('myInput'),
    mask: numberMask
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is included in a blade template, and not through `resources/assets/js/app.js` or any sort of javascript compiler ('webpack' in this case)

Problem is that while most browsers understand ~ `ES6`, there still are limitations to import/require.

Since the `node_modules` is on the server side, the frontend can't just access it.

So what you could/need to do is add this to the mentioned javascript file in one way or another, and compile it with `npm run dev` or similar.

Comment: So what can I do with my code to make this work? Do i have to put some code in my app.js? How does this work?

Comment: Move the contents of the `<script>` tag to e.g. the bottom of `resources/assets/js/app.js`, then run `npm run dev`, assuming you ran `npm install` once in the project before.

Comment: Now it says that vanillaTextMask is not defined. Which I dont quite understand. It is compiling with no errors. How can I make this work? I updated my code

Comment: My bad, you first need to tell npm to install the module to, this can be done by `npm install text-mask-addons --save`, then the above should theoratically work, do run `npm run dev` after the command is done

Comment: It still says that vanillaTextMask is not defined. I installed vanilla-text-mask via NPM but it still says it is not defined. What is causing this?

Comment: You are importing it as `import TextMask` instead of `import vanillaTextMask`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using ES6 Transpiler i.e Babel